# MongoDB Not adding data to the collection c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, rest

I am a new c# developer and am creating an application for my university project. I have to create a REST API in C# that uses mongodb. The delete and get functions work however the post functions do not add a record to the database. I have created the controller, Model and repository as follows:

**Repository**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoNotesAPI.Models;
using MongoNotesAPI.Models.Filters;
using MongoNotesAPI.Services;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using ZstdSharp.Unsafe;
using static MongoDB.Driver.WriteConcern;

namespace MongoNotesAPI.Repositories
{
    public class WeatherRepository : IWeatherRepository
    {
        //Creating a readonly variable to hold our note collection details 
        private readonly IMongoCollection<WeatherSensor> _data;
        
        //Ask for the MongoConnectionBuilder from the dependency injection by requesting
        //it in the parameters of the constructor.
        public WeatherRepository(MongoConnectionBuilder connection)
        {
            //Use the connection to access the database and find the collection
            //called notes. The passing of the Note model into this method indicates that
            //the documents of the collection should be mapped to note objects.
            _data = connection.GetDatabase().GetCollection<WeatherSensor>("WeatherData");
        }


        public void Create(WeatherSensor createdReading)
        {
            _data.InsertOne(createdReading);
        }

        public void CreateMany(List<WeatherSensor> readingList)
        {
            _data.InsertMany(readingList);
        }

        public OperationResponseDTO<WeatherSensor> Delete(string id)
        {
            //Takes the id string and converts it back to an Object Id in the format 
            //requiired by MongoDB
            ObjectId objId = ObjectId.Parse(id);
            //Uses the filter builder to create a single filter that looks for an equals
            //match on the note's id against the provided objId.
            var filter = Builders<WeatherSensor>.Filter.Eq(data => data._id, objId);
            //Use the filter to find the required record and delete it.
            var result = _data.DeleteOne(filter);

            //Check if any records were deleted by mongo db and send back details
            //regarding the success/failure of thr changes
            if (result.DeletedCount > 0)
            {
                return new OperationResponseDTO<WeatherSensor>
                {
                    Message = "Reading Deleted Successfully",
                    WasSuccessful = true,
                    RecordsAffected = Convert.ToInt32(result.DeletedCount)
                };
            }
            else
            {
                return new OperationResponseDTO<WeatherSensor>
                {
                    Message = "No Readings deleted. Please check details and try again.",
                    WasSuccessful = false,
                    RecordsAffected = 0
                };
            }
        }
        public WeatherSensor getHighestTemp(WeatherFilter filter)
        {

           
            var activeFilter = GenerateFilterDefinition(filter);

            var dateQuery = new BsonDocument
            {
                {"DateAdded" , new BsonDocument {
                    { "$gt" , filter.CreatedAfter},
                    { "$lt" , filter.CreatedBefore}
                }}
            };
           
            //Uses the filter builder to create a single filter that looks for an equals
            //match on the note's id against the provided objId.

            //Call the find method using the filter to find the first recod that matches.
            return _data.Find(dateQuery).FirstOrDefault();

        }

        public OperationResponseDTO<WeatherSensor> DeleteMany(WeatherFilter weatherFilter)
        {
            //Passes the provided filter to the method that will build a set of mongo db
            //filter definitions.
            var filter = GenerateFilterDefinition(weatherFilter);
            //Sends the delete request to MongoDB to delete all entries matching the filter
            var result = _data.DeleteMany(filter);

            //Check if any records were deleted by mongo db and send back details
            //regarding the success/failure of thr changes
            if (result.DeletedCount > 0)
            {
                return new OperationResponseDTO<WeatherSensor>
                {
                    Message = "Reading/s Deleted Successfully",
                    WasSuccessful = true,
                    RecordsAffected = Convert.ToInt32(result.DeletedCount)
                };
            }
            else
            {
                return new OperationResponseDTO<WeatherSensor>
                {
                    Message = "No readings deleted. Please check details and try again.",
                    WasSuccessful = false,
                    RecordsAffected = 0
                };
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<WeatherSensor> GetAll()
        {
            //Requests a filter builder for the Note model from the builders class
            var builder = Builders<WeatherSensor>.Filter;
            //Uses the filter builder to create an empty filter(no filter options)
            var filter = builder.Empty;
            //Sends the find request to MongoDB to return all entries matching the filter
            //which in this case will be every entry and then put them in a collection
            return _data.Find(filter).ToEnumerable();
        }

        public IEnumerable<WeatherSensor> GetAll(WeatherFilter weatherFilter)
        {
            //Passes the provided filter to the method that will build a set of mongo db
            //filter definitions.
            var filter = GenerateFilterDefinition(weatherFilter);

            //Sends the find request to MongoDB to return all entries matching the filter
            //which in this case will be every entry and then put them in a collection
            return _data.Find(filter).ToEnumerable();
        }

        public WeatherSensor GetById(string id)
        {
            //Takes the id string and converts it back to an Object Id in the format 
            //requiired by MongoDB
            ObjectId objId = ObjectId.Parse(id);
            //Uses the filter builder to create a single filter that looks for an equals
            //match on the note's id against the provided objId.
            var filter = Builders<WeatherSensor>.Filter.Eq(data => data._id, objId);
            //Call the find method using the filter to find the first recod that matches.
            return _data.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public OperationResponseDTO<WeatherSensor> Update(string id, WeatherSensor updatedReading)
        {
            //Takes the id string and converts it back to an Object Id in the format 
            //requiired by MongoDB
            ObjectId objId = ObjectId.Parse(id);
            //Uses the filter builder to create a single filter that looks for an equals
            //match on the note's id against the provided objId.
            var filter = Builders<WeatherSensor>.Filter.Eq(data => data._id, objId);

            //Create an update builder to allow the creation of our set of update
            //definitions.
            var builder = Builders<WeatherSensor>.Update;
            //Define a set of update definitions(rules) to outline what fields need
            //to be updated and what they need to be updated to.
            var update = builder.Set(data => data.deviceName, updatedReading.deviceName)
                                .Set(data => data.Precipitation, updatedReading.Precipitation)
                                .Set(data => data.Time, updatedReading.Time)
                                .Set(data => data.Latitude, updatedReading.Latitude)
                                .Set(data => data.Longitude,updatedReading.Longitude)
                                .Set(data => data.Temperature, updatedReading.Temperature)
                                .Set(data => data.atmosphericPressure, updatedReading.atmosphericPressure)
                                .Set(data => data.maxWindSpeed, updatedReading.maxWindSpeed)
                                .Set(data => data.solarRadiation, updatedReading.solarRadiation)
                                .Set(data => data.vaporPressure, updatedReading.vaporPressure)
                                .Set(data => data.Humidity, updatedReading.Humidity)
                                .Set(data => data.windDirection, updatedReading.windDirection);

            //Call the update method and give it the filter to find the desired entry as 
            //well as the update definitions of what fields need to be changed.
            var result = _data.UpdateOne(filter, update);

            //Check if any records were chnaged by mongo db and send back details
            //regarding the success/failure of thr changes
            if (result.ModifiedCount > 0)
            {
                return new OperationResponseDTO<WeatherSensor>
                {
                    Message = "Reading Updated Successfully",
                    WasSuccessful = true,
                    RecordsAffected = Convert.ToInt32(result.ModifiedCount)
                };
            }
            else
            {
                return new OperationResponseDTO<WeatherSensor>
                {
                    Message = "No readings updated. Please check details and try again.",
                    WasSuccessful = false,
                    RecordsAffected = 0
                };
            }
        }

        public OperationResponseDTO<WeatherSensor> UpdateMany(WeatherPatchDetailsDTO details)
        {
            //Passes the provided filter parameters to the method to build the filter rules
            //for mongo db.
            var filterDefinitions = GenerateFilterDefinition(details.Filter);
            //Passes the provided details parameters to the method to build the update rules
            //for mongo db.
            var updateDefinitions = GenerateUpdateDefinition(details);
            //Pass the filter and update rules to mongo db to process our request.
            var result = _data.UpdateMany(filterDefinitions, updateDefinitions);

            //Check if any records were chnaged by mongo db and send back details
            //regarding the success/failure of thr changes
            if (result.ModifiedCount > 0)
            {
                return new OperationResponseDTO<WeatherSensor>
                {
                    Message = "Reading/s Updated Successfully",
                    WasSuccessful = true,
                    RecordsAffected = Convert.ToInt32(result.ModifiedCount)
                };
            }
            else
            {
                return new OperationResponseDTO<WeatherSensor>
                {
                    Message = "No reading updated. Please check details and try again.",
                    WasSuccessful = false,
                    RecordsAffected = 0
                };
            }
        }

        //This is an alternate variation of the above upsate mthod which does a full
        //find and replace of the note object.
        public void Replace(string id, WeatherSensor updatedReading)
        {
            //Takes the id string and converts it back to an Object Id in the format 
            //requiired by MongoDB
            ObjectId objId = ObjectId.Parse(id);
            //Uses the filter builder to create a single filter that looks for an equals
            //match on the note's id against the provided objId.
            var filter = Builders<WeatherSensor>.Filter.Eq(data => data._id, objId);
            //Pass the converted object Id into the updated note
            updatedReading._id = objId;
            //Call the replace method and give it the filter to find the desired entry as 
            //well as the updated note details that it will be replaced with.
            _data.ReplaceOne(filter, updatedReading);
        }

        private FilterDefinition<WeatherSensor> GenerateFilterDefinition(WeatherFilter weatherFilter)
        {
            //Requests a filter builder for the Note model from the builders class
            var builder = Builders<WeatherSensor>.Filter;
            //Uses the filter builder to create an empty filter(no filter options)
            var filter = builder.Empty;
    
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(weatherFilter.deviceName) == false)
            {
                //Cleans the original string to remove any charactes that might cause issues with our
                //regex filter by escaping them(like'\n') out in the string.
                var cleanedString = Regex.Escape(weatherFilter.deviceName);

                //Adds a filter to the current filter set. This filter is a contains filter to find if the
                //specified field contains the provided string
                filter &= builder.Regex(data => data.deviceName, BsonRegularExpression.Create(cleanedString));
            }
            /*
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(weatherFilter.id) == false)
            {
                //Cleans the original string to remove any charactes that might cause issues with our
                //regex filter by escaping them(like'\n') out in the string.
                var cleanedString = Regex.Escape(weatherFilter.BodyMatch);
                //Adds a filter to the current filter set. This filter is a contains filter to find if the
                //specified field contains the provided string
                filter &= builder.Regex(data => data.Precipitation, BsonRegularExpression.Create(cleanedString));
            }*/
            if (weatherFilter.CreatedBefore != null)
            {
                //Creates a Less than or equal to filter that checks the created date of the note against the
                //Created before date of the noteFilter
                filter &= builder.Lte(data => data.Time, weatherFilter.CreatedBefore.Value);
            }
            if (weatherFilter.CreatedAfter != null)
            {
                //Creates a greater than or equal to filter that checks the created date of the note against the
                //Created after date of the noteFilter
                filter &= builder.Gte(data => data.Time, weatherFilter.CreatedAfter.Value);
            }

            //Returns the completed filter definitions to the caller.
            return filter;
        }

                                            // TODO  |  \\
                                           //        V   \\
        private UpdateDefinition<WeatherSensor> GenerateUpdateDefinition(WeatherPatchDetailsDTO details ) 
        {
            //Creates a filter builder to allow us to build update rules in a way that
            ////allows us to append extra rules to them afterwards.
            var builder = Builders<WeatherSensor>.Update.Combine();
            //Declare an update definition object which starts as null.
            UpdateDefinition<WeatherSensor> updateRules = null;
            
            //If the title field of the details is not empty, create a new rule for updating the
            //title property in the notes rules.
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(details.deviceName) == false)
            {
                updateRules = builder.Set(data => data.deviceName, details.deviceName);
            }

            //If the title field of the details is not empty, create a new rule for updating the
            //title property in the notes rules.
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(details.deviceName) == false)
            {
                //Check if I have any update rules set yet, if not use the builder to create
                //a new definitions object and set its first rule.
                if (updateRules == null)
                {
                    updateRules = builder.Set(data => data.atmosphericPressure, details.Temperature);
                }
                //If there is already at least one exisiting rule, add a new one to the set. 
                else 
                {
                    updateRules = updateRules.Set(data => data.atmosphericPressure, details.Temperature);
                }
            }

            //Returns the completed update definitions/rules to the caller 
            return updateRules;
        }

        
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace MongoNotesAPI.Models
{
    public class WeatherSensor
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public string ObjId => _id.ToString();
        [BsonElement("deviceName")]
        public string deviceName { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Precipitation")]
        public Double Precipitation { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Time")]
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Latitude")]
        public Double Latitude { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Longitude")]
        public Double Longitude { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Temperature")]
        public Double Temperature { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("atmosphericPressure")]
        public Double atmosphericPressure { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("maxWindSpeed")]
        public Double maxWindSpeed { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("solarRadiation")]
        public Double solarRadiation { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("vaporPressure")]
        public Double vaporPressure { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Humidity")]
        public Double Humidity { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("windDirection")]
        public Double windDirection { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoNotesAPI.Middleware;
using MongoNotesAPI.Models;
using MongoNotesAPI.Models.Filters;
using MongoNotesAPI.Repositories;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace MongoNotesAPI.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors("GooglePolicy")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [ApiKey("Guest")]
    public class WeatherController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IWeatherRepository _repository;
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public WeatherController(IWeatherRepository repository, IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        // GET: api/Notes
        [HttpGet]
        [HttpHead]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherSensor> Get()
        {
            //Sends a message to the repository ot request it to retrieve all
            //entries from the database
            return _repository.GetAll(); ;
        }

        // GET: api/Notes/Filtered
        [HttpGet("Filtered")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherSensor> Get([FromQuery] WeatherFilter filter)
        {
            //Sends a message to the repository ot request it to retrieve all
            //entries from the database
            return _repository.GetAll(filter);
        }

        [HttpHead("Filtered")]
        public ActionResult GetHeaders([FromQuery] WeatherFilter filter)
        {
            //Gets all records mathing the filter and finds the most recent one.
            var record = _repository.GetAll(filter).OrderByDescending(n => n.Time).FirstOrDefault();
            //Add a custom header to output the created date of the most recent record.
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("last-created", record.Time.ToLocalTime().ToString());

            //Get the count of how many entries match the filter
            int count = _repository.GetAll(filter).Count();
            //Add a custom header to output the number of records that would be returned.
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("record-count", count.ToString());

            return Ok();
        }

        // GET api/<NotesController>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult Get(string id, [FromQuery]string apiKey)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            return Ok(_repository.GetById(id));
        }

        // POST api/<NotesController>
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Post([FromBody] WeatherSensor? createdNote)
        {
            if (createdNote == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            //Use a try catch to catch anny erors if the MOngo Db requests
            //causes an exceptrion
            try
            {
                _repository.Create(createdNote);
                return Ok("New Record Added");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Send a problem error code if any issues occur.
                return Problem(detail: ex.Message, statusCode: 500);
            }

         
        }
        
        // POST api/Notes/PostMany
        [HttpPost("PostMany")]
        public ActionResult PostMany([FromBody] List<WeatherSensor>? createdNotes)
        {
            if (createdNotes == null || createdNotes.Count == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _repository.CreateMany(createdNotes);
            return Ok();
        }

        // PUT api/<NotesController>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public ActionResult Put(string id, [FromBody] WeatherSensor updatedNote)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) || updatedNote == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _repository.Update(id, updatedNote);
            return Ok();
        }

        // PATCH api/Notes/UpdateMany
        [HttpPatch("UpdateMany")]
        public ActionResult UpdateMany([FromBody] WeatherPatchDetailsDTO? details)
        {
            //Check if a valid set of update details was provided.
            if (details == null)
            { 
                return BadRequest(); 
            }
            //Check if at least one of the update fiields has detilas to send to the database
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(details.deviceName) )
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            //Check that we have at least 1 valid filter optoin set, otherwise the update will
            //target every document in the collection.
            if (details.Filter.CreatedBefore == null && details.Filter.CreatedAfter == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _repository.UpdateMany(details);
            return Ok();
        }

        // DELETE api/<NotesController>/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        [ApiKey("ADMIN")]
        public ActionResult Delete(string id, string apiKey)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
            {
                return BadRequest("A valid _id is required to perform this operation");
            }

       

            //Process the reauest and store the details regarding the success/failure of the 
            //request
            var result = _repository.Delete(id);
            //If the request show a failure, inform the user.
            if (result.WasSuccessful == false) 
            { 
                return BadRequest(result);
            }
            //Otherwise, send an Ok(200) message
            return Ok(result);
        }
        [HttpGet("GetHighestTemp")]
        public ActionResult GetHighestTemp(WeatherFilter filter)
        {
            _repository.getHighestTemp(filter);
            return Ok();
        }

        //DELETE: api/Notes/DeleteOlderThanGivenDays
        [HttpDelete("DeleteOlderThanGivenDays")]
        public ActionResult DeleteOlderThanDays([FromQuery]int? days) 
        {
            //Check if a days value is provided and that it complies with our business rules 
            if (days == null || days <= 30)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            WeatherFilter filter = new WeatherFilter
            {
                //Add a created before filter to our filter details to be used for building our
                //filter definitions later. The calculation in the add days section ensures the value
                //will result in a past date, not a future one by accident.
                CreatedBefore = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Math.Abs((int)days) * -1)
            };

            //Process the reauest and store the details regarding the success/failure of the 
            //request
            var result = _repository.DeleteMany(filter);
            //If the request show a failure, inform the user.
            if (result.WasSuccessful == false)
            {
                result.Message = "No records found within that range";
                return Ok(result);
            }
            //Otherwise, send an Ok(200) message
            return Ok(result);
        }

        [HttpDelete("DeleteByTitleMatch")]
        public ActionResult DeleteByTitleMatch([FromQuery] string? searchTerm)
        {
            //Validate our user input to ensure it meets our busines rules.
            if (searchTerm == null || searchTerm.Length <=3 )
            {
                return BadRequest("This endpoint requires a search parameter provided " +
                                                                "of more then 3 Characters ");
            }

            WeatherFilter filter = new WeatherFilter
            {
                //Create a new note filter object which takes the search term and will later be
                //passed to the delete method to delete based upon thr term provided.
               // id = searchTerm
            };

            //Process the reauest and store the details regarding the success/failure of the 
            //request
            var result = _repository.DeleteMany(filter);
            //If the request show a failure, inform the user.
            if (result.WasSuccessful == false)
            {
                return BadRequest(result);
            }
            //Otherwise, send an Ok(200) message
            return Ok(result);
        }

       

    }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas please let me know, thanks :)

I tried using Bson elements, ensuring they match the mongodb collection, i have gone through and ensured the database connections function, they work for the users collection but not the weather data section.
**Response**
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CTKo.png)

Comment: At first sight, your code looks fine. Do you get an error message? What happens when you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: As a side note: please reduce the code in your question to the relevant parts to make it easier for others to comprehend.

Comment: There is no error message, i get a 200 for the post request, I will ensure I reduce the code next time